# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(function() {
        $("#country").val("<?php echo $_SESSION['country'];?>");
     });
})
```

```
<td>Country:</td>
<td colspan="2"><select name="country" id="country">
    <option value="93">93-Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="355">355-Albania</option>
    <option value="213">213-Algeria</option>
    <option value="1-684">1-684-American Samoa</option>
    <option value="376">376-Andorra</option></td>
```

i am trying to select my drop-down list based on users selection. This code was given by one of the current user however there is this Syntax-error occur. What can i do to solve this?

Comment: .val() is used to get the current value of the first element. Do you wish to set it to the selected element? Maybe you could change .val() to .html(), and then give it a try.

Comment: can share some more code..code seems to correct

Comment: Don't really understand your explanation but the user selection is store in  $_SESSION['country'] and i want to set the default selected dropdown value same as  $_SESSION['country']

Comment: then you should have used `$("#country option:selected").val("<?php echo $_SESSION['country'];?>");` <--- the option with the value of `$_SESSION['country']` will be the selected option

Comment: well the same error occur

Comment: You missing something else this is the right syntax ...

Comment: what does this session variable contains - $_SESSION['country']? verify if its echoing correct value. Otherwise your jquery syntax is correct.

Comment: There is no syntax error in that code.

Comment: It is in correct value

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){} and $(function() {}); which are equivalent.. Use either one of them ..

Comment: if you echo `$_SESSION['country']` what does it give?

Comment: 355 it is my countryCode

Comment: @RohitKumar we *have* checked it first, maybe you also need to check with us? http://jsfiddle.net/xnpofy0q/

Comment: thanks @Hanky웃Panky ,i take my word back , but may you describe me what is benefit with this .. what about http://jsfiddle.net/nnLu37qs/

Comment: Yep that is another question. I didn't say their code was the best. That can certainly be improved. I just meant the syntax error that OP has mentioned does not lie in the code they have posted.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution for this problem to go thrrough the appropiate selection , something as below -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var v="<?php echo $_SESSION['country'];?>";
 $('#country option[value='+v+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
}) ;
```

And unnecessarily you are using

`$(document).ready(function(){} and $(function() {});` which are equivalent..  Use either one of them

**LIVE**  http://jsfiddle.net/mailmerohit5/ndxzpo3c/